# Property Binding & Sync in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I'm having trouble syncing my properties in vue.js, I have an 'active' property that I want to set to the value of each instance 'plan', but at the same time I would like to sync the property with the parent, with no luck. What am I doing wrong ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Vue</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="http://bootswatch.com/paper/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.3/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
      <div id="app">
        <pre>
          @{{ $data | json}}
        </pre>
        <div v-for="plan in plans">
          <plan :active.sync="active" :plan.sync="plan"></plan>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <template id="plan_template">
      <div>
        <span >@{{ plan.name }}</span>
        <span >@{{ plan.price }}/month</span>
        <button @click="setActivePlan" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">UPGRADE</button>
      </div>
  </template> 

  <script>
    new Vue({
      el:'#app',
      data:{
        plans:[
          {name:'Executive',price:100},
          {name:'Professional',price:50},
          {name:'Personal',price:30},
          {name:'Free',price:0}
        ],
        active:{},

      },

      components:{
        plan:{
          template:'#plan_template',

          props:['plan', 'active'],

          methods:{
            setActivePlan:function(){
              this.active=this.plan;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Note: This answer applies to V2 of Vue JS, < 2.3.0.

## If you are using up V2.3.0+ then you can use `.sync` and `.once` modifiers: [documentation here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier)

You are using version 2 of Vue. The `.sync` and `.once` modifiers have been removed. From the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#once-and-sync-Modifiers-on-v-bind-removed):

> Props are now always one-way down. To produce side effects in the parent scope, a component needs to explicitly emit an event instead of relying on implicit binding.

I have modified your code to use events here:

```js
new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data:{
    plans:[
      {name:'Executive',price:100},
      {name:'Professional',price:50},
      {name:'Personal',price:30},
      {name:'Free',price:0}
    ],
    active:{},
  },
  methods: {
    setActivePlan: function(plan) {
      this.active = plan;
    }
  },

  components:{
    plan:{
      template:'#plan_template',

      props:['plan', 'active'],

      methods:{
        setActivePlan:function(){
          // emit an event to the parent indicating that this is the active plan
          this.$emit('activate-plan');
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="http://bootswatch.com/paper/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.3/vue.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div id="app">
    <div v-for="plan in plans">
      <plan :plan="plan"
            :active="active"
            @activate-plan="setActivePlan(plan)"
            >
      </plan>
    </div>
    <pre>
      {{ JSON.stringify($data, null, 2) }}
    </pre>
  </div>
</div>

<template id="plan_template">
  <div>
    <span >{{ plan.name }}</span>
    <span >{{ plan.price }}/month</span>
    <button @click="setActivePlan" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">UPGRADE</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: this is not true anymore as it was reintroduced in [2.3.0+](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#sync-Modifier)